I need a word for the atmosphere between two people
I am looking for a word, preferably a noun, to describe the space created between two people depending on their relationship. Similar to the concept of multiplicity, where two or three people singing can sound like several people, where something is created from the combination of two other things. This is a neutral word that describes the space between two people but not the character of the space.
For example, if a brother and sister had a hostile, hateful relationship and you were sitting in between them-that space- or if two best friends have a warm, loving relationship and you sat between them-that space. I am thinking along the lines of hygge (Danish word that refers to a warm safe comforting feeling of being home that is created by intentionally introducing specific elements ie candles, hot soup, cozy blanket, warm conversation, appreciation of nature/simple things/holding space to be present and savor simple moments ), What I am looking for in this case refers to the space that is created by the relationship between two people regardless of the connotation/condition of the relationship but the space exists as a result of the relationship. A noun that refers to the landscape created by the relationship.
Example sentence: Although Jane was patient and kind, and Jim was caring and gentle, the space between them was cold and harsh.
The tense and hostile space created by Mr. and Mrs. Smith was not conducive to nurturing the well being of their children.
Editing based on comment suggestions

What thesaurus alternatives have you found that are nearby but not what you want? Start with 'relationship' or 'atmosphere'. Also this is one place where ChatGPT can help (ask for alternatives with example sentences).

What is wrong with the word 'atmosphere'? Other than that - aura, vibe, mood or intersubjectivity?

Atmosphere comes close to what I am looking for, but since it can be applied to so many contexts, I was hoping to find a word that refers to the space/atmosphere specifically created by the relationship between two people. A specific atmosphere that is created from the fallout of a relationship. So the character of the place/atmosphere would be dependent upon the nature of the relationship, but it is not the relationship/vibe/chemistry itself.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The word vibe might work.
Cambridge defines it as:

the mood of a place, situation, person, etc. and the way that they make you feel

TFD defines it as:

A distinctive emotional quality or atmosphere that is sensed or experienced by someone


vibe is slang.

@Vector It is somewhat informal, but OP didn't specify what register they're writing in. Certainly The New York Times is willing to use it.

I'm old school :-) - go back to the days before there was even such a word at all. Then it became a word used by college kids - derived from "good vibrations" - originally from the hippies of the 1960's. Now it has slipped into vernacular English because those college kids grew up - there are many similar terms in use. But. it still sounds 'slangy' to me.

@Vector there is nothing wrong with slang. Slang is very much an integral part of language and how native speakers use it, so unless the question specifies a more formal register, I don't see any problem with slang at all. By the way, according to etymonline, "Meaning 'intuitive signal about a person or thing' was popular late 1960s, but has been recorded as far back as 1899". So unless you are very old school, the use predates you :)

I don't mind using slang where it applies. The reason I upvoted chemistry and rapport below is that the question specifically mentions two people. A vibe can be between two people but doesn't have to be. As this answer also cites, it doesn't even have to be about people per se.

Either "vibe" or "vibes" works very well here. They connote being produced by humans, particularly their mood and attitude, and radiated out into nearby space. It'd be perfectly natural to say you feel uncomfortable with "the vibes" in a room due to two people's relationship.

@terdon - Didn't mean to imply there was anything wrong with slang - just stating an FYI, since the OP apparently isn't  too familiar with English. 1899 - I did not know it dated that far back. I surmise it was used in that period because of the 'spirituality' fad of that era - seances, ouija boards, etc. Fell out of usage until it was revived again in the 1960's, and then continued on to become part of contemporary vernacular.

@Vector fair enough. I thought you were somehow saying that slang shouldn't be posted as an answer. Thanks for clarifying. And I had absolutely no idea it was that old either! I would have assumed 60s too, but I have been bitten by this too often now, and have found many words or phrases that I thought were young are actually much older, so I checked and found it interesting.

You are most likely looking for chemistry (definition # 3 below). The specific (positive) definition # 4 below is synonymous with rapport which is typically used in positive contexts.

Although Jane was patient and kind, and Jim was caring and gentle, the
chemistry between them was cold and harsh.

Collins:

chemistry in American English
NOUN

the interaction of one personality with another
The chemistry between him and his boss was all wrong

sympathetic understanding; rapport
the astonishing chemistry between the actors




Yes to chemistry, but I have only heard it used in a positive sense...  two actors have a great chemistry and work well together, or two characters have a chemistry that makes the reader suspect they might fall in love later

@nuggethead it can be used in a negative sense. See sense 3 in the Collins definition above.

This word is probably closest to the requested meaning, because it is very often used to refer to the connection between two specific people rather than the general atmosphere of a group. However it can also be used to refer to a group of people, as for example in referring to members of a musical band.

In Spanish we use the word "energy", I don't know if it can be applied to English:

Que buena energía genera este entorno
What good energy this environment generates


Entre ellos dos hay una muy buena energíaBetween the two of them there is a very good energy


I think in English you'd normally talk of an individual having a certain kind of energy (see this Reddit thread). It doesn't mean something created by two people interacting.

I grew up on the west coast of the US, and we'd definitely refer to "the energy between the two of them". I now live on the East Coast, and when I use language like that people say to me "you're such a Californian!".

How about undercurrent? You can use that in both positive and negative senses:

There was an undercurrent between them, full of passion and excitement.


There was an undercurrent between them, harsh and foreboding.


Mood, perhaps

a conscious state of mind or predominant emotion; a prevailing attitude; the way you feel at a particular time


Rapport might work:
Cambridge Dictionary- rapport(2)
Agreement or sympathy between people or groups:

           Either 

It was as if I could feel our souls become electrified as two became one. Like a moth to a flame our semi-conscious selves became one conscious soul guided to each other if only through the Either.
And in my times of need. As if she could never leave. Her essence can be felt beside mine. Almost as if she never died. I now spend my time now thanking the HEAVENS not only for The Either.
                  For Rina
;


I suspect you mean ether rather than either.

Disposition    'The disposition between the two of them was very low'
Collins gives:

Someone's disposition is the way that they tend to behave or feel.


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

That example isn’t idiomatic English.
